# XOR statement in PuLP python

Tags: python-3.x, pulp

I am working on PuLP in python and I want to model the following statement :

x is positive XOR y is positive, where x ans y are integer.

How can I convert this in PuLP code ?

I started with
[XOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ekkr.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? HINT: You're dealing with boolean logic so you'll need binary variables. The sudoku example problem in the docs uses binary varibles so might be a help: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/a_sudoku_problem.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kabdulla.  Binary variables would be the way to go here.

Expanding on that idea a little further: You can use binary variables to indicate whether X is positive (TRUE/1) by a constraint such as `M*binary_variable_for_x <= X` where M is a sufficiently large number for the problem that would not limit X.  Then the binary_variable_for_x can be 1 if X > 0.

Do the same for when Y is positive (TRUE/1).

And then you could write another constraint that requires the sum of these booleans   to be >= 1.

`binary_variable_for_x + binary_variable_for_y >= 1`

There's multiple ways to formulate the problem, but this can be one way.